# how can I return a String?

Tags: java, string, return

```
package book1;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public abstract class Book  {
    public String Book (String name, String ref_num, int owned_copies, int     loaned_copies ){
    return;

    }
}

class Fiction extends Book{
    public Fiction(String name, String ref_num, int owned_copies, String author) {

            }

        }
```

at the moment when i input values into the variable arguments and call them with this :

```
public static class BookTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Book> library = new ArrayList<Book>();
        library.add(new Fiction("The Saga of An Aga","F001",3,"A.Stove"));
        library.add(new Fiction("Dangerous Cliffs","F002",4,"Eileen Dover"));


        for (Book b: library) System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println();


    }
}
```

i get a return value of this:

```
book1.Fiction@15db9742
book1.Fiction@6d06d69c
book1.NonFiction@7852e922
book1.ReferenceBook@4e25154f
```

how can i convert the classes to return a string value instead of the object value? I need to do this without changing BookTest class. I know i need to use to string to convert the values. but i don't know how to catch the return value with it. could someone please point me in the right direction on how to convert this output into a string value?

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the `toString()` method in your `Book` or `Fiction` class. The method is actually declared in the `Object` class, which all classes inherit from.

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return ""; // Replace this String with the variables or String literals that you want to return and print.
}
```

This method is called by `System.out.println()` and `System.out.print()` when they receive an object in the parameter (as opposed to a primitive, such as `int` and `float`).

To reference the variables in the method, you'll need to declare them in the class and store them via the class's constructor.

For example:

```
public abstract class Book {
    private String name;
    private String reference;
    private int ownedCopies;
    private int loanedCopies;

    public Book (String name, String reference, int ownedCopies, int loanedCopies) {
        this.name = name;
        this.reference = reference;
        this.ownedCopies = ownedCopies;
        this.loanedCopies = loanedCopies;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return name + ", Ref:" + reference + ", OwnedCopies: " + ownedCopies + ", LoanedCopies: " + loanedCopies; // Replace this String with the variables or String literals that you want to return and print.
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i reference the variables as they are an argument and not all of them are inherited. such as author.

Comment: You need to store them in a member variable in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You need to overwrite the toString() Method of your Book class. In this class you can generate a String however you like. Example:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.append(this.author).append(": ").append(this.title);
  return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The classes you have defined, don't store any values. It is in other words useful to construct a new book. You need to provide fields:

```
public abstract class Book {

    private String name;
    private String ref_num;
    private int owned_copies;
    private int loaned_copies;

    public String Book (String name, String ref_num, int owned_copies, int loaned_copies) {
        this.name = name;
        this.ref_num = ref_num;
        this.owned_copies = owned_copies;
        this.loaned_copies = loaned_copies;
    }

    public String getName () {
        return name;
    }

    //other getters

}
```

Now an object is basically a set of fields. If you want to print something, you can access and print one of these fields, for instance:

```
for (Book b: library) System.out.println(b.getName());
```

In Java, you can also provide a default way to print an object by *overriding* the `toString` method:

```
@Override
public String toString () {
    return ref_num+" "+name;
}
```

in the `Book` class.

Answer (score 0):

Need to give your object Book a ToString() override.

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=55

Example:

```
@Override public String toString()
{
    return name;
}
```

Where name, is a string in the Class.

Comment: Show how you tried. You probably didn't match the signature. Use the @Override annotation to prevent that problem.

Comment: Wow a down vote for the right answer... okay.

As Kon said, post what didn't work and we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping that you have assigned the passed arguments to certain attributes of the classes. Now, once you are done with that, you can override the toString() method in `Book` to return your customized string for printing.